# Creation of a Visio Add-in with Visual Studio 2010 and C# : loosing reference to buttons

Tags: visual-studio-2010, button, add-in, visio

I am facing something strange in my Visio Add-in:

I have a `CommandBar`, with `CommandButtons` on it and I just launch my debug mode.

The first page is OK (the start page of Visio) but if I open a file or create a new file, I can click all I want on my buttons, **nothing is working !**

It worked perfectly on the start page but not on my new visio file...

I tried to comment parts of my code, but the issue seems to come from nowhere... I really do not understand.

If someone already faced this kind of behaviour, please help, I just do not know what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting ".Tag" property for your button to some unique value.

More info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa201791.aspx,
"Maintaining references to command bar controls when contexts change"